# I get some wired error with JOptionPane it says IllegalArgumentException

Tags: java, swing, jscrollpane

I tried to do some GUI by myself and i found an example on the youtube where one is using it. it works on his screen but not on my computer.

this is the code example

```
    SP_CONVERSATION.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_NEVER);
    SP_CONVERSATION.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(ScrollPaneConstants.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
    SP_CONVERSATION.setViewportView(TA_Conversation);
    MainWindow.getContentPane().add(SP_CONVERSATION);
    SP_CONVERSATION.setBounds(10, 90, 330, 180);
```

it says this

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid horizontalScrollBarPolicy
at javax.swing.JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(Unknown Source)
```

And i kinda new to this, so i dont know what to do

Comment: Not sure what this has to do with a JOptionPane. Looks like you are playing with a JScrollPane. I suggest you read the Swing tutorial on [How to Use Scroll Panes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/scrollpane.html) for examples and explanations. Doin't use setBounds() to size and position components. The tutorial also has a section on Using Layout Managers. Also, follow standard Java naming conventions. Varialble names are not upper cased. If all this doesn't help then you need to post a SSCCE that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Srry tagged the wrong tag

Comment: You still haven't fixed the title and you still haven't posted a SSCCE.

Answer (score 1):

Change the constants to `JScrollPane` as below, and it should work.

```
SP_CONVERSATION.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
SP_CONVERSATION.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_ALWAYS);
```

Comment: Found the problem. it was because i had to
SP_CONVERSATION.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy
SP_CONVERSATION.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy in anorther place just with anorther names. but i dont know why it was showing me the wrong error

Comment: @DritonCazimi, and that is exactly why you post a SSCCE with your question. Most of the time when you post code snippets you post code that is not related to the problem.