# Why is this happening? ScrollbarPane

Tags: java, swing

I am getting this error

"Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: invalid horizontalScrollBarPolicy
at javax.swing.JScrollPane.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.java:554)
at com.company.Main.main(Main.java:39)"

What exactly am I doing incorrectly?

```
import com.sun.org.apache.bcel.internal.generic.JsrInstruction;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JPanel panel = new JPanel();
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();

        //set frame
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.setSize(700, 700);
        frame.setMaximizedBounds(new Rectangle(0,0,1000,1000));
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(1000,1000));
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(frame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        // create text field
        JTextField answer = new JTextField();
        answer.setBounds(100, 270,300, 30);
        answer.setFont(new Font("default", Font.BOLD, 18));
        JLabel input = new JLabel("input");
        input.setBounds(100, 240, 80, 40);
        input.setFont(new Font("default",Font.ITALIC, 20));
        //set panel
        panel.setLayout(null);
        panel.add(answer);
        panel.add(input);

        JScrollPane inner_window = new JScrollPane();
        panel.add(inner_window);
        inner_window.setLayout(null);
        inner_window.setBounds(100, 300, 500, 300);
        inner_window.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.HORIZONTAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);
        inner_window.setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);


        // allows window to open in center (frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);)
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }
    public static void SlowPrint(){

    }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15838510/i-get-some-wired-error-with-joptionpane-it-says-illegalargumentexception

Comment: This `inner_window.setLayout(null);` completely invalidates the JScrollPane's functionality. Get rid of that line if you want a functioning scroll pane

Comment: Java GUIs have to work on different OS', screen size, screen resolution etc.  using different PLAFs in different locales.  As such, they are not conducive to pixel perfect layout.  Instead use layout managers, or [combinations of them](http://stackoverflow.com/a/5630271/418556) along with layout padding and borders for [white space](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17874718/418556). .. To expand on the useful tip from @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter. ;)

Comment: @DontKnowMuchButGettingBetter thank you, also what should I set as its layout then? should i not set a layout?

Comment: *"what should I set as its layout then(?)"* Not layout, more often **layout*s***. Combine them as linked in my comment. Related: Provide ASCII art or a simple drawing of the *intended* layout of the GUI at minimum size, and if resizable, with more width and height - to show how the extra space should be used.

Comment: LayoutManagers are a programmer's best friend. Setting them to null makes things much more difficult than you can imagine. Also, you have a typo: you're setting the Horizontal scrollbar policy twice.

Comment: You don't touch or change the JScrollPane's layout. It is unusual and used by this component only, and is required for it to function.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot pass a vertical scrollbar policy to a *setHorizontalScrollBarPolicy*.
You probably meant `inner_window.setVerticalScrollBarPolicy(JScrollPane.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR_AS_NEEDED);`